# Can we call method in DoWork event?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am exporting a Data Table to excel file using background worker. And I wanted to show the export progress using progress bar. Do we have to write the exporting code in Do Work event or can we call a method, which is present in other class.
In my code I tried calling different method. But its not working. 
Below is the sample code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    property = new Property();
    this.DataContext = property;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exported Successfully");
    }
}

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Export export = new Export();
    export.GenerateExcelFile();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part of the code where your worker raises the `worker_ProgressChanged` and `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [worker.ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx) from `worker_DoWork` with a valid progress value

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    worker.ReportProgress(0);
    // Some job 
    worker.ReportProgress(10); 
    // ...
    // Finish
    worker.ReportProgress(100);
}
```

I'm not sure how you are generating report. Further I'm supposing your `pbStatus` has `Minimum="0"` and `Maximum="100"`. You can after exporting each row report progress something like that.

```
worker.ReportProgress(currentRow * 100.0 / totalRows);
```

You also set your progress bar intermediate if you are not sure how to calculate that by setting `progress.IsIndeterminate` to `true`

```
pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;
```

Comment: Thank you @Adnan Umer. The solution has helped me solve the issue.